# How do I read an unlimited number of rows through Excel?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 100 rows in Excel and I want to perform the test on every one of the 100 rows How do I do this?

```
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Sales")).Click();
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Sales Panel")).Click();
ExcelLib.PopulateInCollection(@"C:\Users\Numg\Desktop\webusers\Book1.xlsx");
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.Id("web_user_user_id")).SendKeys(ExcelLib.ReadData(2, "Id"));             
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Ok")).Click();
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Delete")); // gets a collection of elements with Delete as a link
while (links.Any()) 
{
    links.ElementAt(0).Click(); 
    PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.Id("remove_shares"));
    PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]")).Click();
    links = PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("Delete"));
}                      PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.Id("4")).Click();
var option = PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.Id("aggrupations_653_shares"));
var SelectElement = new SelectElement(option);
SelectElement.SelectByValue("3");
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#bet-group > #send > i.fa.fa-arrow-right")).Click();
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.Id("code")).SendKeys("testQA");
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#new_reduction > input[name=\"commit\"]")).Click();
PropertiesCollections.driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Clear")).Click();
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Jeff you can easily google this problem and can easily find out solution, there are multiple ways one way is to traverse data row one by one or can pass excel sheet as any data type and can traverse through a loop.